# Apply image overlay when hovering exactly within the image

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have two flexbox columns. The left column contains text; the right column contains a picture. The columns should take up 60% and 40% of the width of the page, respectively. The text is longer than the picture is tall. I'd like a semi-transparent overlay on the picture; when I hover on the overlay, I'd like the overlay to disappear.

However, I can't get the overlay to show up, and I can't seem to restrict the hover area to just the size of the picture -- anywhere in the right column, even below the picture, triggers the hover effect.

Because I want the page to be responsive, I don't want to manually set the picture's size (or `aspect-ratio`): it should fill the width of the right column, and the right column should fill 40% of the page's width -- no `px` here, please.

Here's a quick mockup of what I'm trying to do. In this example, the yellow `#img-container` expands below the bottom of the image, and the green `.overlay` doesn't show up. Both should be exactly the size of the image.

[Fiddle here.](https://jsfiddle.net/t0knrLpq/36/)

Am I going about this the right way? Is there something obvious I'm missing? I'm pretty new to web design... thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To be able to put an *overlay* over a specific element:

- you will need the element you are overlaying (your `#container-img`) to be `position: relative`.
- The *overlay* itself must be positioned 'relative' to that element with `position: absolute`.
- Depending on your requirements the *overlay* is positioned inside the element by assigning values to `top`, `right`, `bottom` and/or `left` or, as I used in the snippet, define their shorthand `inset` property. As you want to *overlay* the image, `inset: 0` will stretch the *overlay* to all sides of its parent `#container-img`.
- All that is left to do is define CSS for when `#container-img` is hovered.

I commented my changes and additions in the snippet:

```css
#container {
  display: flex;
  gap: 50px;
}

#container-text {
  flex: 3;
}

#container-img {
  flex: 2;
  background-color: yellow;
  align-self: flex-start;
}

/*************************/
/* Changes and additions */
/*************************/
/* Changed */
#container-img img {
  display: block; /* removes small whiete space below image */
  /* disable this property to see the difference! */

  width: 100%;
  opacity: 20%;
}

#container-img .overlay {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    inset: 0; /* shorthand for T/R/B/L properties */
    background: rgb(0,255,0,.2); /* a semi transparent color */
}

/* ADDED */
#container-img {
  position: relative; /* new stacking context to position overlay */
}
#container-img:hover .overlay {
  display: none; /* hide the overlay on hover */
}
```

```html
<div id="container">

  <div id="container-text">
    <p>teeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeext</p>
    <p>text</p>
    <p>text</p>
    <p>text</p>
    <p>text</p>
    <p>text</p>
    <p>text</p>
    <p>text</p>
    <p>text</p>
    <p>text</p>
    <p>text</p>
    <p>text</p>
  </div>

  <div id="container-img">
    <img src="https://play-lh.googleusercontent.com/IeNJWoKYx1waOhfWF6TiuSiWBLfqLb18lmZYXSgsH1fvb8v1IYiZr5aYWe0Gxu-pVZX3" alt="profile picture">
    <div class="overlay"></div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Perfect, this is exactly what I was looking for. I think I assumed something like `align-self: flex-start;` was already implicitly active